# Is there any example of a simple Abelian ring which is not domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, noncommutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is called:

- simple if it has no two-sided ideal;
- a domain if it has no zero divisor;
- abelian if each idempotent of $R$ is central.

Is there any example of a simple abelian ring which is not a domain?

Comment: What about matrix rings?

Comment: @MattAllegro : idempotents are not central in general in matrix rings

Comment: Since a non-trivial central idempotent generates a non-trivial ideal, "simple abelian" is equivalent to "simple with no non-trivial idempotent".

Comment: Hmm... I don't know any examples like this...

Comment: Should I take on a ring with unity? Your definition of simple ring indicates yes.

Comment: @freshman probably yes but maybe a ring without unity also can work.

Comment: What have you tried???

Comment: Thinking about a ring without unity, your definition of simple ring doesn't assume $R^2\neq0$. For example, $A=2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is a simple ring under your definition and $A^2=0$. Some people realize simple ring like you have written (they don't assume $R^2\neq0$ in the definition) and others people assume $R^2\neq0$. Should I assume $R^2\neq0$ or not?

Comment: @Cary I think you should just say "with identity." If nothing else, a famous example by Smoktunowicz  gives you a simple nil ring, which can only have $0$ as an idempotent.   `Smoktunowicz, Agata. "A simple nil ring exists." Communications in Algebra 30.1 (2002): 27-59.`

Answer (score 4):

Carl Faith, in

*Faith, C.*, [**Noetherian simple rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1964-11193-9), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 70, 730-731 (1964). [ZBL0132.02301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0132.02301)

asked whether there was a simple Noetherian (i.e., both left and right Noetherian) ring that had no nontrivial idempotents but was not a domain.

This was answered with an example in

*Zalesskij, A. E.; Neroslavskij, O. M.*, [**There exist simple Noetherian rings with zero divisors but without idempotents**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927877708822167), Commun. Algebra 5, 231-244 (1977). [ZBL0352.16011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0352.16011).

That paper is in Russian, and I don't have access to it, but

*Lorenz, Martin*, [**$K_ 0$ of skew group rings and simple Noetherian rings without idempotents**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-32.1.41), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 32, 41-50 (1985). [ZBL0573.16004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0573.16004)

gives more examples.

Maybe without the Noetherian condition there are easier examples, but I haven't thought of any.